# Echo two different user's column

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to echo an information from another account's line, to be shown on page.

exemple: If user Aaron  logins,  and goes to page "Yasmine" i want to echo Yasmine's picture.

This is my code now

PHP:

```
mysql_select_db("vestiged_sala");  


$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$pPoza = '';

// add these lines in place of $result query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $pPoza = $row['pPoza'];
    }

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div class="pPoza"><?php
echo $pPoza;
?></div>
```

The problem is that i echo the Aaron's profile picture instead of Yasmine's

Comment: Oh, done. Thank you, answer it so i can select your answer as best one

Comment: Okay, moved to an answer.

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run a `SELECT` like you are for the current user's data.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= ?
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid= ?
```

You also should update your driver to `PDO` or `mysqli` so you can use parameterized queries as I've shown here. This will prevent SQL injections and quote your data correctly.

You can read more here:

1. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php (or...)
3. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php (...dont use PDO and `mysqli`, (nor `mysql_` all separate)